# Node.js+Socket.io, established connections are increasing

Tags: node.js, networking, amazon-web-services, socket.io, connection-leaks

My node.js+socket.io server has deploying via aws ec2 instances.

and there are some network tuning configs.

```
echo 1024 65535 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range

echo 60 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
echo 10 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
echo 3 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes

echo 10 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
echo 20000 > /proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog
echo 2048 > /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
```

and i've monitoring connection states with netstat command.

```
netstat -anl | grep ":22000" | awk '/^tcp/ {t[$NF]++}END{for(state in t){print state, t[state]} }'
```

then, found "ESTABLISHED" connections are increasing steadly.

```
TIME_WAIT 12
ESTABLISHED 304
LAST_ACK 1
LISTEN 1
```

how can i detect abnormal connection and disconnect it?

if established state connection reached over 4000, then clients cannot connect to the server.

how can i fix it? help me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is caused by ping timeouts.

A fix that could help is to go to:
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/socket.js

Find this:

```
Socket.prototype.setPingTimeout = function () {
  var self = this;
  clearTimeout(self.pingTimeoutTimer);
  self.pingTimeoutTimer = setTimeout(function () {
    self.transport.close();
    self.onClose('ping timeout');
  }, self.server.pingInterval + self.server.pingTimeout);
};
```

Add the line which says self.transport.close();

According to github issues for socket.io this should solve the issue. However, you could also wait and hope that this is going to be in the next release.